# Crash: startActivity in Android API 34

Tags: android, kotlin, android-api-34

Does anyone know what this error means and what I can do about it:

*FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.familiekoning.radionedplus, PID: 3772
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.familiekoning.radionedplus/com.familiekoning.radionedplus.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.familiekoning.radionedplus: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)*

It happens with:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent) //CRASH in Android 34
```

and only in Android API34

Also a crash when I make the intent explicit with the same error:

```
val explicitIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
explicitIntent.setPackage("com.familiekoning.radionedplus")
startActivity(explicitIntent) //CRASH in Android 34
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14, You can read security tab

Comment: Thx, it still crashes somehow. I changed the message above with the new code. Would be nice if you can help me out ;)

Comment: @PatrickKoning It looks like you are registering a receiver if you are getting that message, but you aren't showing us where you're calling `registerReceiver`. If you can edit that call into your question, the help can be more specific. (If you aren't making that call anywhere, it is possible that one of your dependencies is, in which case editing in your build script might help.) Otherwise, based on what you've shared so far, Yunus's documentation link is very likely the best you can get.

Comment: I figured it out. In MainActivity I indeed registered some receivers without a third parameter: RECEIVER_EXPORTED. I changed that and now it works fine. Thx for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

> In MainActivity I indeed registered some receivers without a third parameter: RECEIVER_EXPORTED. I changed that and now it works fine.

As Yunus linked in the comments, this is one of the new security features for Android 14 (API level 34) as documented at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14 .